# scala BigDecimal Gson json formatting

Tags: json, scala, gson

If I have the following code in Java

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(new BigDecimal(10).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)));
```

It prints 
`10.00` , exactly what I want.

However, if I have the same code in scala this time,

```
println(new Gson().toJson(BigDecimal(10).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)))
```

It prints:

```
{"bigDecimal":1.00,"mc":{"precision":34,"roundingMode":"HALF_EVEN"},"computedHashCode":1565550863}
```

which is not what I want. How can I fix it to print just 10? I am assuming I will have to configure Gson library somehow for scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you're probably working with `java.math.BigDecimal`, while in other you're working with `scala.math.BigDecimal`.

You can work with Java `BigDecimal` in Scala as well, e.g.

```scala
import java.math.{BigDecimal => JBigDecimal}
println(new Gson().toJson(new JBigDecimal(10).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)))
```

This prints only `10.00` which is what you want.

---

Btw, if you only need the string representation of `BigDecimal`, why don't you just use `toString`?

```scala
scala>     println(BigDecimal(10).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toString)
10.00
```

Comment: You are correct that I can use java's BigDecimal. But I wonder why that happens. As for the toString, its mentioned here as an example. My actual use case is to use Gson to automatically create json from a scala object that contains scala BigDecimal

Comment: I ended up using java.math.BigDecimal

Comment: @kk1958 I would guess that Gson has a special case for Java's BigDecimal, but not Scala's.